# JPQL createNativeQuery with join failing

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql, toplink

I'm joining 2 entities with a foreign key relationship in the db, but not in the code (saving the why for another question):

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT u.* FROM user u JOIN user_community_organization uco ON "
                + "u.user_id = uco.user_id "
                + "WHERE uco.community_id = :communityId "
                + "AND lower(u.email) = :email", User.class)
                .setParameter("communityId", communityId)
                .setParameter("email", email.toLowerCase());
```

But the query fails during runtime with:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds  to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near ':communityId AND 
lower(u.email) = :email' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: SELECT u.* FROM user u JOIN user_community_organization uco ON  
u.user_id = uco.user_id WHERE uco.community_id = :communityId AND lower(u.email) = :email
```

I've tried different variations, moving the parameters in and out of the ON bit, removing lower. Nothing works.

Before I added the join:

```
em.createQuery("select object(o) from User as o where lower(o.email) = :email");
        q.setParameter("email", email.toLowerCase());
```

This query worked fine.

What am I doing wrong?
Running on GlassFish3.1, toplink and mySql.

Comment: Are you sure you're showing us the real code? The SQL log shows that the parameters have not been replaced. Why do you use a native SQL query and not a JPQL query?

Comment: @JB Nizet that is the subject for my next question - there's a 3 way link involved and I haven't been able to get it working using jpql, so in the interim I'm doing it the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is with native query but your second example uses JPQL so it's not really clear what you are trying to do. i think your native query fails because named parameters are not supported in JPA (only positional parameters, but Hibernate for example does support it). So, try this

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT u.* FROM user u JOIN user_community_organization uco ON "
                + "u.user_id = uco.user_id "
                + "WHERE uco.community_id = ?1 "
                + "AND lower(u.email) = ?2", User.class)
                .setParameter(1, communityId)
                .setParameter(2, email.toLowerCase());
```

As for JPQL version, you didn't post entity code so I'll make a guess about relations, but it would look something like this

```
em.createQuery("select u from User u where lower(u.email) = :email and u.communityOrganisation.id = :communityId");
        q.setParameter("email", email.toLowerCase());
        q.setParameter("communityId", communityId);
```

Comment: doh, how'd I miss that?  Thanks.